# Is primarily opinion based a valid close reason for TGO?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

From a discussion on another thread: [here](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/a/509/2766) 
[image]

Is the close reason

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert
>   experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost
>   entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific
>   expertise.

valid for TGO?

Is this simply left over from all SE sites growing out of Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can draw the line at a different degree of opinion-ness, but we should still have this close reason. Consider some possible questions from someone thinking to buy an X and considering Y feature in it:

These three really are **not good questions**. They don't help other people later, and they don't much help the asker now unless the answerer happens to provide a ton of detail that wasn't explicitly asked for.

- *what X should I buy?*
- *are X's with Y worth the extra money?*
- *should my X have a Y?*

These three **are better**. They may still involve opinion (how important is a window in a tent, how heavy is too heavy for a backpacker, how cold or warm is too cold or warm) but they have some objective component and they aren't asking us to make a decision for the asker.

- *what difference does it make if my X has a Y?*
- *what are the advantages of a Y for my X?*
- *How do I decide about a Y for my X?*

We can close the first three as primarily opinion based and encourage them to be edited into something more like the last three.

Comment: Great answer Kate. I hope we can avoid being *that* strict (like SO) while attracting new people with quality questions/answers.

Comment: I've rephrased slightly to make the distinction more...erm...distinct :)

Comment: How about down voting with a recommendation for improvement instead of an outright close vote? Particularly for new users. Personally, I would start with just a comment or edit.

Comment: @ppl A vote to close is milder than a downvote. Closing is not outright and can always be undone by others. Close votes **are** recommendations for improvement

Answer (score 1):

### No, this is a valid close reason

SO was created as a response to programming forums. These forums provide opinions not answers to questions. SO (and therefore SE) was created in response to the frustration of not finding a good answer to a good question. Just lists of people contradicting each other.

TGO should be the same. TGO should be based on facts and not opinions. There are many outdoor forums where opinions are great but TGO should provide answers to questions based on **facts** not opinions. This is what differentiates us from everyone else.

As stated [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199784/217110) questions of this nature should state the problem they are facing so that users can provide an answer. Asking for opinions is not a question nor a problem.

I know we want to grow the community but this should not be at the expense of the SE ethic.

All the other sites abide by this rule, why are we any different?

Comment: I do not know the history of SO but I would imagine that the opinion based close reason got implemented later on after the web site already had a fair amount of activity. The ability to up or down vote in itself is a huge improvement over forums.